# How to remove "baca" or read from the html?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I managed to create a simple program to webscrape urls and translate the html extracted into English. However, for this particular website (link below), "html.find_all('p')" also extracts unwanted 'p' tags embedded with anchor tags.

Example 1: HTML that I do not want

```
<p>Baca: <a href="https://nasional.tempo.co/read/1216929/soenarko-sarankan-kivlan-zen-berhati-hati-omongan-diviralkan">Soenarko Sarankan Kivlan Zen Berhati-hati Omongan Diviralkan</a></p>
```

Example 2: HTML that I want

```
<p>"Ya, jadi penangguhan penahanan ini, pertama kami memang mengajukan penangguhan penahanan," kata Ferry membuka sesi wawancara. Hari itu, Mabes Polri telah mengabulkan penanggungan penahanan terhadap Soenarko yang menjadi tersangka kepemilikan senjata ilegal.</p>
```

Is there a way that I can use to get the code to filter out example 1 and only keep example 2?

```
link = "https://nasional.tempo.co/read/1216914/moeldoko-penangguhan-penahanan-soenarko-bisa-diterima"

webpage_response = requests.get(link)
webpage = webpage_response.content
page = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

html_title = page.find("title")
title2 = html_title.get_text()
title = title2.strip("- Bisnis Tempo.co")

html = page.find(attrs={"itemprop": "articleBody"})
text = html.find_all("p")
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide if condition to check if there any 'Baca' text and skip that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
link = "https://nasional.tempo.co/read/1216914/moeldoko-penangguhan-penahanan-soenarko-bisa-diterima"

webpage_response = requests.get(link)
webpage = webpage_response.content
page = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

html_title = page.find("title")
title2 = html_title.get_text()
title = title2.strip("- Bisnis Tempo.co")

html = page.find(attrs={"itemprop": "articleBody"})
items = html.find_all("p")

for item in items:
    if not ('Baca' in item.text):
        print(item)
```

---

Or you can use decompose() function to remove.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
link = "https://nasional.tempo.co/read/1216914/moeldoko-penangguhan-penahanan-soenarko-bisa-diterima"

webpage_response = requests.get(link)
webpage = webpage_response.content
page = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

html_title = page.find("title")
title2 = html_title.get_text()
title = title2.strip("- Bisnis Tempo.co")

html = page.find(attrs={"itemprop": "articleBody"})
items = html.find_all("p")

for item in items:
    if 'Baca' in item.text:
        item.decompose()

print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://nasional.tempo.co/read/1216914/moeldoko-penangguhan-penahanan-soenarko-bisa-diterima")
if r.status_code == 200:
    page = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    html = page.find(attrs={"itemprop": "articleBody"})
    # find 'p' elements but without nested elements
    for item in html.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'p' and len(list(tag.children)) <= 1):
        print(item)
```

output

```
<p>"Panglima TNI kan pembina bagi para purnawirawan, jadi dengan pertimbangan-pertimbangan tersendiri Panglima melakukan itu," kata Moeldoko, saat ditemui di Gedung Krida Bakti, Komplek Istana Negara, Jakarta Pusat, Jumat, 20 Juni 2019. Ia mengapresiasi langkah Panglima memberikan jaminan penangguhan penahanan itu.</p>
<p>Moeldoko mengatakan meski saat ini berstatus tersangka kasus kepemilikan senjata ilegal, namun Soenarko tetap seorang purnawirawan TNI. "Pertimbangan-pertimbangan Panglima, pasti sudah dipertimbangkan masak-masak," kata Moeldoko.</p>
<p>Selain Hadi, penjamin penangguhan penahanan Soenarko adalah Menteri Koordinator Bidang Kemaritiman, Luhut Binsar Panjaitan. Kepala Biro Penerangan Masyarakat Mabes Polri Brigadir Jenderal Dedi Prasetyo mengatakan alasan Luhut bersedia menjamin penangguhan penahanan adalah karena Soenarko tokoh senior di TNI.</p>
<p>Menteri Koordinator Bidang Politik, Hukum, dan Keamanan Wiranto mengatakan senjata itu berasal dari Aceh. Senjata itu diperkirakan ada kaitannya dengan kerusuhan 22 Mei 2019.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand how does the lambda tag work, but am I right to say it instructs python to find all the "p" without any children tags?

Comment: @JeffersonNg Yes. This is right. Feel free to vote up if the solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use :not and :contains pseudo class selectors to specify paragraphs to exclude if contain certain text. I would make a little more robust in this case by extending the exclusion test text as in the page and add the id to restrict to the article content.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs #4.7.1
import requests

r = requests.get('https://nasional.tempo.co/read/1216914/moeldoko-penangguhan-penahanan-soenarko-bisa-diterima/full&view=ok')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
paras = [p.text for p in soup.select('#isi p:not(:contains("Baca juga:"))')]
print(paras)
```